# Retrieve the right data based on if the application is ran for the first time or not

Tags: java

I want to retrieve some data from an API but based on if its the first run then it should retrieve the data from start of the year but if it is the next run then it should retrieve only the new data (i.e. the data available only after the previous run).

My question is what would be the best way to save and retrieve the timestamp between the run.

Comment: An easy way would be to have an integer that starts at 0 everytime the application is pulled up. If int == 0, retrieve first data, else, retrieve second data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html) to store and read an application specific marker in a system independent way.

```
package com.preferencetest;

import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class PreferenceTest {

  private static final String RUN_MARKER = "RUN_MARKER";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Obtain a Preferences node for this class name.
    final Preferences pref = Preferences.userRoot().node(
        PreferenceTest.class.getName());

    // Read the RUN_MARKER value. For the first start this should be the
    // default value false.
    final boolean previouslyStarted = pref.getBoolean(RUN_MARKER, false); 

    if(!previouslyStarted) {
      // First run: Set the marker to true.
      pref.putBoolean(RUN_MARKER, true);
      System.out.println("First run");
    } else {
      System.out.println("This is not the first run.");
    }
  }
}
```